# Update JavaScript with Django view values

Tags: django, django-templates

In the js file below

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
    buildchart()
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        buildchart();
    });
    $('#mobile-collapse').on('click', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            buildchart();
        }, 700);
    });
});
function buildchart() {
    $(function() {
        var graph = Morris.Donut({
            element: 'chart-pie-moris',
            data: [{
                    value: 60,
                    label: 'Order'
                },
                {
                    value: 20,
                    label: 'Stock'
                },
                {
                    value: 10,
                    label: 'Profit'
                },
                {
                    value: 5,
                    label: 'Sale'
                }
            ],
            ......
```

I want to be updating the values in `buildchart()` function the values returned by my views file functions.
**Example**

```
def order(request):
    a = 'calculated integer value'
    return a
```

So I would like to pass in `order` function to replace **60** in `buildchart()` function.
how can I achieve this? Please help a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use a Django variable inside JavaScript**

Just, surround the Django variable by `" "` or `' '`.
Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{someDjangoVariable}}";
   var b = "{% url 'someDjangoUrl' %}";
</script>
```

**If you want use access in a external js file**
Define the variable in the html file inside a `<script>` block.
And access to it in the external `.js` file like a *normal js global variable* :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{someDjangoVariable}}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="{% static 
'path/to/your_js_file.js' %}">
// In this file you can have access to the 'a' variable.
</script>
```

Comment: Am using an external JavaScript file. So the JavaScript  code is not in my html file

Comment: I wasn't able to access it in the external js file

Comment: How are you organized your scripts files ?

Comment: In my html, am referencing the js file with `<script src="{% static 'js/pages/dashboards_ecommerce.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: Inside the `dashboards_ecommerce.js` is where I have the js file I used in the question

Comment: Normally, you just have to load the external js file just after the `<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{someDjangoVariable}}";
</script>` . Did you do that ? i ask because i use is always and it work

Comment: Yeah it works fine now. I was  loading the external js file before `<script type="text/javascript"> var a = "{{someDjangoVariable}}"; </script>`